# Firebase REST API query with different keys

Tags: firebase, api, rest, firebase-realtime-database, querying

So this is the structure of my Firebase DB right now, I am using the Firebase REST API:

```
"company": {
      
   company1_id {
        id: company_id,
        userId: userid,
        name: name
        //someotherstuff
}
    company2_id {
        id: company_id,
        userId: userid,
        name: name,
        //someotherstuff
}

}
```

Soo, right now I am getting the companies belonging to one user by calling :

```
"firebasedbname.firebaseio.com/company.json?orderBy="userId"&equalTo=userId"
```

This works perfectly fine and gets the corresponding data, but now I want it to order the companies alphabetically by name, and then i try this:

```
"firebasedbname.firebaseio.com/company.json?orderBy="name"&equalTo=userId"
```

But this time, it returns no data! Even though i have added .indexOn: "name" to the company node.Any help will be aprreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering), if you want to filter data you need to first "specify how you want your data to be filtered using the `orderBy` parameter", and then you need to "**combine** `orderBy` with any of the other five parameters: `limitToFirst`, `limitToLast`, `startAt`, `endAt`, and `equalTo`".

So if you added "an `.indexOn: "name"` to the `company` node", it means that you intend to query as follows:

```
https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/company.json?orderBy="name"&equalTo="companyName"
```

You cannot order by `(company) name` and filter on `userId`.

If you want to get all the companies corresponding to a specific user and order them by the company name, you will need to use `?orderBy="userId"&equalTo=userId"` **and** do the sorting in the client/application calling the REST API.

Comment: @MonishB Hi, did you have the time to look at the answer?